# ADB does not detect one of my devices

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

So when testing an AndroidStudio Application on that tablet from my computer everything worked fine. Though when I try to do the same from my laptop, the tablet is not shown. Tried the same using my smartphone and it worked, but the app shall be optimized for tablets.
When using `adb shell` or `adb devices` command, the tablet cannot be found though the smartphone is accessable.

Tablet: Acer Iconia 10 B3-A30

What I already tried:

- `adb kill-server` -> `adb start-server`
- restarting laptop and tablet
- reinstalling drivers (I am not 100% sure I tried the right ones, because I wasn't able to find any drivers for the B3-A30, so I tried the ones for A3-A30. This should not matter anyway, since the Device-Manager knows the name of the tablet and does not show a yellow "!")

Neither of these possible solutions I found did work.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the drivers for google adb.

Go to Device Manager -> Find the Device -> Right Click and Update Driver -> Browse my computer... -> Let me Pick... -> Android Device** and Click Next -> Choose Google inc and Android ADB Interface.

** if you cant see any Android Device drivers go to [Download Universal ADB](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/)